# Asynchronous Google Maps loading bug in IE

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asynchronous, requirejs

I've had a look for this bug all over the place and not found anything that works. Here's the code:

```
MapsLoader.prototype._setup = function () {
    var promise = new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve) {

        // Callback for Google Maps that resolves the promise
        window.gmapsLoaded = function () {
            console.log('[Maps Loader] Loaded');
            resolve();
        };

        console.log('[Maps Loader] Loading...');

            // Create a URL with the API key pointing to the gmapsLoaded callback
        var mapsURL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' + config.googleMaps.APIKey + '&sensor=false&callback=gmapsLoaded',

            // Create script object
            script = $('<script />').attr('src', mapsURL);

        $('head').append(script);
    });

    // Remove the gmapsLoaded function from global scope
    promise.then(function () {
        window.gmapsLoaded = undefined;
    });

    // Return the promise
    return promise;
};
```

It's part of a `MapsLoader` module that simply adds in the Google Maps script to the `head` (only when required), waits for the Google Maps load callback, and then resolves the promise (at which point the file that uses it can start doing stuff).

Works well in Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and IE10. However in IE 8 and 9 I get an error:

- `Object doesn't support property or method 'Load'` (IE9)
- `Object doesn't support property or method` (IE8)

Which is coming from line 55 of the `main.js` Google Maps file:

```
k.google.maps.Load(...)
```

This occurs *after* the "[Maps Loader] Loaded" log message, so the callback is running and the page continues to load normally except that the Google Maps area is blank.

If I turn caching on (i.e. not using IE Developer Tools) the page will sometimes work the second time, suggesting it's perhaps some sort of loading race condition.

I was able to fix it by loading the Google Maps code in the `head` in conditional comments, so it would only load on all pages in IE (and then detecting if `google` already exists in the `MapsLoaded` module). This did work, but it's not pleasant and I'd rather find the route cause.

---

Other information: I use RequireJS for module loading.

Things I've tried:

- Using the `async=2` parameter on the Google Maps URL (as suggested [here](http://lostmonocle.com/post/88217865/jquery-getscript-and-the-google-maps-api))
- Appending to the `body` instead of `head` (as on the Google API examples)
- Placing everything in a `$.ready` call

---

Thanks

Comment: Managed to get Chrome to give the same result by adding the load script to the head twice in quick succession (before it had a chance to load in for the first one).

Comment: And looking at the elements inspector in IE Developer Tools it's loading in two copies of the Google Maps `main.js` file...

Comment: If I surround everything in the Promise block with an `if (typeof google === 'undefined') {...}` and turn caching on in IE everything works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `$.getScript(mapsURL)` (i.e. loading it via an AJAX request) instead of manually appending a script to the `head` seemed to work.

Not sure why loading it in this way should make a difference, but it did.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this script `<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js"></script>` in index file in your project.
Issue is causing due to improper support polyfill in project.